# Converting Python dictionary to ctypes structure

Tags: python, c, dictionary, ctypes

I have a Python dictionary with the following entries:

```
Tmp={'Name1': [10.0, 20.0, 'Title1', 1], 'Name2': [5.0, 25.0, 'Title2', 2]}
```

I want to pass this to a C-function where the function is defined as:

```
struct CA {
   char *Keys;
   float *Values;
   char *Title;
   int Index;
};

void myfunc (struct CA *in, int n);
```

On the Python side, I created an equivalent ctypes structure as:

```
class CA(ctypes.Structure):
   _fields_ = [("Keys", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)), 
               ("Values", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)), 
               ("Title", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)), 
               ("Index", ctypes.c_int)]
```

and created an array of CA using:

```
CAarray = CA * 2
```

Now I want to assign Tmp to CAarray in a loop such that

```
k = Tmp.keys()
for (j, _) in enumerate(k):
   CAarray[j].Keys   = _ 
   CAarray[j].Values = Tmp[_][:2] 
   CAarray[j].Title  = Tmp[_][2]
   CAarray[j].Index  = Tmp[_][3]
```

I have been struggling to get the syntax correct, and have failed so far. Help.

On the side, is there any routine/lib which can handle inter-conversion between Python variables and ctypes variables?

Answer (score 10):

I created a test DLL to verify the structure would pass correctly.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

struct CA {
   char* Keys;
   float* Values;
   char* Title;
   int Index;
};

__declspec(dllexport) void myfunc (struct CA* in, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d: Keys = %s\n", i, in[i].Keys);
        printf("%d: Values = %f %f\n", i, in[i].Values[0], in[i].Values[1]);
        printf("%d: Title = %s\n", i, in[i].Title);
        printf("%d: Index = %d\n", i, in[i].Index);
    }
}
```

Here's how I called it:

```py
#!python3
from ctypes import *

class CA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('Keys', c_char_p),
                ('Values', POINTER(c_float)),
                ('Title', c_char_p),
                ('Index', c_int)]

Tmp={'Name1': [10.0, 20.0, 'Title1', 1], 'Name2': [5.0, 25.0, 'Title2', 2]}

# repackage Tmp as a list of CA structures
ca_list = []
for k, v in Tmp.items():
    ca = CA()
    ca.Keys = k.encode('utf8') # Python 3 strings are Unicode, char* needs a byte string
    ca.Values = (c_float * 2)(v[0], v[1]) # Interface unclear, how would target function know how many floats?
    ca.Title = v[2].encode('utf8')
    ca.Index = v[3]
    ca_list.append(ca)

# repackage python list of CAs to ctype array of CAs
ca_array = (CA * len(ca_list))(*ca_list)

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.myfunc.argtypes = POINTER(CA), c_int
dll.myfunc.restype = None

dll.myfunc(ca_array, len(ca_array))
```

Output:

```
0: Keys = Name1
0: Values = 10.000000 20.000000
0: Title = Title1
0: Index = 1
1: Keys = Name2
1: Values = 5.000000 25.000000
1: Title = Title2
1: Index = 2
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks Mark, it works. The crucial part is encoding the string by 'utf8'. I could modify Rolika's solution to the point where all the values where correctly captured by C-function, except for the string which only received the first character. Your solution helped solve the last bit...

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about this, but it seems to work:

```
tmp = {'Name1': [10.0, 20.0, 'Title1', 1], 'Name2': [5.0, 25.0, 'Title2', 2]}

class CA(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("key", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p)),
           ("values", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)),
           ("title", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p)),
           ("index", ctypes.c_int)]

CAArray = CA * 2
ca_array = CAArray()

for ca, key in zip(ca_array, tmp):
    ca.key = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_wchar_p(key))
    ca.values = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_float(tmp[key][0]))
    ca.title = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_wchar_p(tmp[key][2]))
    ca.index = tmp[key][3]

for ca in ca_array:
    print(ca.key[0], ca.values[0], ca.values[1], ca.title[0], ca.index)
```

I sticked to Python naming conventions though.

Comment: Sorry rolika, it doesn't work. When ca_array is passed to C function myfunc (see the query), I get all messed-up values. Note that the first argument of myfunc is an array of structure CA.